# Can sparklyr be used with spark deployed on yarn-managed hadoop cluster?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparkapi, sparklyr

Is the [`sparklyr` R package](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr) able to connect to YARN-managed hadoop clusters? This doesn't seem to be documented in the [cluster deployment](http://spark.rstudio.com/deployment.html#cluster_deployment) documentation. Using the `SparkR` package that ships with Spark it is possible by doing:

```
# set R environment variables
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR=...)
Sys.setenv(SPARK_CONF_DIR=...)
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...)
Sys.setenv(SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS=...)

spark_lib_dir <- ... # install specific
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(sparkr_lib_dir, .libPaths()))
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "yarn-client")
```

However when I swaped the last lines above with

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client")
```

I get errors:

```
Error in start_shell(scon, list(), jars, packages) : 
  Failed to launch Spark shell. Ports file does not exist.
    Path: /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/bin/spark-submit
    Parameters: '--packages' 'com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34' '--jars' '<path to R lib>/3.2/sparklyr/java/rspark_utils.jar'  sparkr-shell /tmp/RtmpT31OQT/filecfb07d7f8bfd.out

Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/mpollock/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/mpollock/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:<path to spark install>/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.11 added as a dependency
com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-pom added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 480ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    :: modules in use:
    -----------------------------------------
```

Is `sparklyr` an alternative to `SparkR` or is it built on top of the `SparkR` package?

Comment: Looking at the [sparkapi](https://github.com/rstudio/sparkapi) readme the answer to the last question is clearly "it is an alternative to SparkR". Still not sure how to use `master='yarn-client'` though

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486163/sparklyr-ports-file-and-java-error-mac-os - seems that the issue keeps popping up in different OS & configurations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sparklyr can be used against a yarn-managed cluster. In order to connect to yarn-managed clusters one needs to:

1. Set SPARK_HOME environment variable to point to the right spark home directory.
2. Connect to the spark cluster using the appropriate master location, for instance: `sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client")`

See also: http://spark.rstudio.com/deployment.html

Comment: I tried setting SPARK_HOME which took, but the ports file issue remains. It is not clear to me exactly what `spark_connect` is looking for or where it is looking. Is it necessary to pull out names and ports from `yarn-site.xml`?

Comment: Currently, `sparklyr` is an alternative to `sparkr`; I have not tried using them both side-by-side since this is currently unsupported. Could you confirm that you are running your script without the `sparkr` library loaded. If that still does not work, could you dump your system information: OS, version, x86/x64, spark redistribution, etc for us to take a look and reproduce this? Would also be appreciated to open this issue under http://github.com/rstudio.sparklyr to have more people helping unblock this.

Comment: I finally got things working by adding `config=list()` to the inputs of `spark_connect()`. Seems that the error message is a bit misleading. Is the real issue around getting the spark packages installed?

Comment: In older versions of `sparklyr` we specified a CSV package that during `spark_connect()`, Spark would download from Spark's online package repo and therefore, `spark_connect()` required internet connectivity unless `config = list()` was specified to override adding this CSV package. Newer versions of `sparklyr` embed the CSV package to avoid requiring internet connectivity and the `config=list()` is no longer required for offline clusters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can but there is one catch to everything else that has been written, which is very elusive in the blogging literature, and that centers around configuring the resources.

**The key is this**: when you have it executing in local mode you do not have to configure the resources **declaratively**, but when you execute in the YARN cluster, you absolutely do have to declare those resources. It took me a long time to find the article that shed some light on this issue but once I tried it, it Worked.

Here's an (***arbitrary***) example with the key reference:

```
config <- spark_config()
config$spark.driver.cores <- 32
config$spark.executor.cores <- 32
config$spark.executor.memory <- "40g"

library(sparklyr)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/local/spark")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR = '/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/conf')
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR = '/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/conf')

config <- spark_config()
config$spark.executor.instances <- 4
config$spark.executor.cores <- 4
config$spark.executor.memory <- "4G"

sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn-client", config=config, version = '2.1.0')
```

[R Bloggers Link to Article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sparklyr-a-test-drive-on-yarn/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly using Cloudera Hadoop (CDH)?

I am asking as I had the same issue when using the CDH-provided Spark distro:

```r
Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME')
[1] "/usr/lib/spark"  # CDH-provided Spark
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client")
Error in sparkapi::start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home,  : 
      Failed to launch Spark shell. Ports file does not exist.
        Path: /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit
        Parameters: --jars, '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr.jar', --packages, 'com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0','com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34', sparkr-shell, /tmp/Rtmp6RwEnV/file307975dc1ea0.out

Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/oracle/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/oracle/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.7.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.11 added as a dependency
com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-pom added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-csv_2.11;1.3.0 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 in central
    found com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1 in central
    found com.
```

However, after I downloaded a pre-built version from Databricks (Spark 1.6.1, Hadoop 2.6) and pointed `SPARK_HOME` there, I was able to connect successfully:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/home/oracle/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6') 
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client") # OK
library(dplyr)
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
src_tbls(sc)
[1] "iris"
```

Cloudera does not yet include `SparkR` in its distribution, and I *suspect* that `sparklyr` may still have some subtle dependency on `SparkR`. Here are the results when trying to work with the CDH-provided Spark, but using the `config=list()` argument, as suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/114) from `sparklyr` issues at Github:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master='yarn-client', config=list()) # with CDH-provided Spark
Error in sparkapi::start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home,  : 
  Failed to launch Spark shell. Ports file does not exist.
    Path: /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit
    Parameters: --jars, '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/R/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr.jar', sparkr-shell, /tmp/Rtmpi9KWFt/file22276cf51d90.out

Error: sparkr.zip does not exist for R application in YARN mode.
```

Also, if you check the rightmost part of the `Parameters` part of the error (both yours and mine), you'll see a reference to `sparkr-shell`...

(Tested with `sparklyr` **0.2.28**, `sparkapi` 0.3.15, R session from RStudio Server, Oracle Linux)

Comment: Thanks much. I am however on a HDP cluster with spark 1.6.1 - so the under-the-hood R methods should be available in spark. The issue seems to be that I lack a certain port config file that is not apparently needed for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade to `sparklyr` version `0.2.30` or newer is recommended for this issue. Upgrade using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")` followed by restarting the r session.

Comment: Thanks for following up, but updating (to 0.2.31) did not resolve the port file issue. The spark installation on my cluster does not seem to have the config file that is expected. `sparklyr` tried to call `.../spark/bin/spark-submit` but the config files are `.../spark/conf` which has things like `hive-site.xml` and`spark-defaults.conf` but no "ports" file.

Comment: I should note that this spark installation has been heavily used with both `pyspark` and `SparkR` without issue.