# Sparklyr Ports File and Java Error MAC OS

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

```
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
Error in sparkapi::start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home,  : 
Failed to launch Spark shell. Ports file does not exist.
Path: /Users/XXX/Library/Caches/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit
Parameters: --jars, '/Users/XXX/Library/R/3.3/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr.jar', --packages, 'com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0','com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34', sparkr-shell, /var/folders/dy/jy43zcgd7gv27qc0mzlxxvd1qt7rhg/T//RtmptbAxW4/file357f67d0745a.out

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I'm trying to Start sparklyr in R and getting above message. Any solutions or suggestions to resolve this error please? I'm using MAC OSX and below are the details from Session Info. It dosent work even with

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = list())

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0     sparklyr_0.2.28

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.5     sparkapi_0.3.15 digest_0.6.9    withr_1.0.2          assertthat_0.1 
[6] rappdirs_0.3.1  R6_2.1.2        DBI_0.4-1       git2r_0.15.0    magrittr_1.5   
[11] httr_1.2.1      curl_0.9.7      config_0.1.0    devtools_1.12.0 tools_3.3.1    
[16] readr_0.2.2     parallel_3.3.1  yaml_2.1.13     memoise_1.0.0   tibble_1.1
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102921/can-sparklyr-be-used-with-spark-deployed-on-yarn-managed-hadoop-cluster - seems that the issue keeps popping up in different OS & configurations

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue is resolved in `sparklyr` version `0.2.30` or later. Upgrade using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")` followed by restarting your r session.