# sparklyr - Connect remote hadoop cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

It is possible to connect sparklyr with a remote hadoop cluster or it is only possible to use it local?
And if it is possible, how? :)

In my opinion the connection from R to hadoop via spark is very important!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Hadoop or Spark cluster? If Spark, you can try to connect through [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy), details here:
https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr#connecting-through-livy

Note: Connecting to Spark clusters through Livy is under experimental development in sparklyr

Comment: I mean connect to Hadoop via Spark. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure what type of Spark installation you have - if it's on yarn then Spark can read data from HDFS. So the answer is: yes. However, I am afraid that you need to provide more information to get a good hint on what you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My data are stored in a Cloudera Hadoop Cluster. To access the data via hive with an JDBC-Connection works fine with are. Is this with sparkly also possible? If yes, how? :)

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102921/can-sparklyr-be-used-with-spark-deployed-on-yarn-managed-hadoop-cluster

Answer (score 0):

You could use [livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/) which is a Rest API service for the spark cluster.

once you have set up your [HDinsight](http://%22https://livytest.azurehdinsight.net/livy/batches%22) cluster on Azure check for livy service using curl

```
#curl test
curl -k --user "admin:mypassword1!" -v -X GET 


#r-studio code
sc <- spark_connect(master = "https://<yourclustername>.azurehdinsight.net/livy/",
                     method = "livy", config = livy_config(
                       username = "admin",
                       password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Livy password:")))
```

Some useful URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-livy-rest-interface