# connecting to spark standalone cluster does not work within RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, sparkr

I created a virtual machine running an ubuntu server 16.04. I've already installed spark and all dependencies & prerequisites. My Spark cluster is running on the VM and all workers and the master can be started by start-all.sh. 
Now I'm trying to submit sparkR jobs to this cluster by using Rstudio from my local computer. I specified the sparkContext with master="spark://192.168.0.105:7077" to connect to the cluster, which is obviously running, when calling the IP:8080 master webUI. Is there any config, that has been specified, to call the master from another device, which is not part of the cluster yet?

The error in R is:

> Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem

Comment: Have you installed `sparklyr` on your local computer?

Comment: i have got sparklyr and sparkR and both are not executing my jobs

Comment: `8080` is usually Ambari, which usually means HDP & Yarn... if so try `master="yarn://192.168.0.105:7077"`

Comment: I think it's `master="yarn-client://192.168.0.105:7077"` for spark version < 2

Comment: spark://192.168.0.105:7077 did work to connect to the spark master, the cluster manager master is distributing the jobs, but they never get executed.

Comment: so you've checked the logs? the log directory should be set in `spark-env.sh`

Comment: I usually put my SparkR scripts into an R file that I submit with RScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Livy rest api interface. 
https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

see [sparklyr - Connect remote hadoop cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074042/sparklyr-connect-remote-hadoop-cluster/54339710#54339710)