# sparklyr write data to hdfs or hive

Tags: sparklyr

I tried using sparklyr to write data to hdfs or hive , but was unable to find a way . Is it even possible to write a R dataframe to hdfs or hive using sparklyr ? Please note , my R and hadoop are running on two different servers , thus I need a way to write to a remote hdfs from R .

Regards
Rahul

Comment: Have you tried to run Spark in yarn mode? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102921/can-sparklyr-be-used-with-spark-deployed-on-yarn-managed-hadoop-cluster) post might be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Writing Spark table to hive using Sparklyr:

```
iris_spark_table <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
sdf_copy_to(sc, iris_spark_table)
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "create table iris_hive as SELECT * FROM iris_spark_table")
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. this loads the data into hive's default database. do you know how to change the hive database for which to export the file?

Comment: @bshelt141 You can use syntax `database.table` in the SQL passed to `DBI`.

Answer (score 5):

As of latest sparklyr you can use `spark_write_table`. pass in the format `database.table_name` to specify a database

```
iris_spark_table <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
spark_write_table(
  iris_spark_table, 
  name = 'my_database.iris_hive ', 
  mode = 'overwrite'
)
```

Also see this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886236/sparklyr-can-i-pass-format-and-path-options-into-spark-write-table-or-use-savea/51886474#51886474) where i got some input on more options

Answer (score 0):

You can use sdf_copy_to to copy a dataframe into Spark, lets say tempTable. Then use `DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "INSERT INTO TABLE MyHiveTable SELECT * FROM tempTable")` to insert the dataframe records in a hive table.