# sparklyr can I pass format and path options into spark_write_table? or use saveAsTable with spark_write_orc?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

Spark 2.0 with Hive

Let's say I am trying to write a spark dataframe, `irisDf` to orc **and** save it to the hive metastore

In Spark I would do that like this,

```
irisDf.write.format("orc")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("path", "s3://my_bucket/iris/")
    .saveAsTable("my_database.iris")
```

In `sparklyr` I can use the `spark_write_table`function,

```
data("iris")
iris_spark <- copy_to(sc, iris, name = "iris")
output <- spark_write_table(
   iris
  ,name = 'my_database.iris'
  ,mode = 'overwrite'
)
```

But this doesn't allow me to set `path` or `format`

I can also use `spark_write_orc`

```
spark_write_orc(
    iris
  , path = "s3://my_bucket/iris/"
  , mode = "overwrite"
)
```

but it doesn't have the `saveAsTable` option

Now, I CAN use `invoke` statements to replicate the Spark code,

```
  sdf <- spark_dataframe(iris_spark)
  writer <- invoke(sdf, "write")
  writer %>% 
    invoke('format', 'orc') %>% 
    invoke('mode', 'overwrite') %>% 
    invoke('option','path', "s3://my_bucket/iris/") %>% 
    invoke('saveAsTable',"my_database.iris")
```

But I am wondering if there is anyway to instead pass the `format` and `path` options into `spark_write_table` or the `saveAsTable` option into `spark_write_orc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`path` can be set using `options` argument, which is equivalent to `options` call in the native `DataFrameWriter`:

```
spark_write_table(
  iris_spark, name = 'my_database.iris', mode = 'overwrite', 
  options = list(path = "s3a://my_bucket/iris/")
)
```

By default in Spark, this will create a table stored as [Parquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet) at `path` (partition subdirectories can be specified with the `partition_by` argument).

As of today there is no such option for format, but an easy workaround is to set `spark.sessionState.conf.defaultDataSourceName` property, either on runtime

```
spark_session_config(
  sc, "spark.sessionState.conf.defaultDataSourceName", "orc"
)
```

or when you create a session.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MichaelChirico. Parquet has been default source, since the beginning of the data source API, so unless it is configured explicitly, you can expect it will be consistent across versions.

Answer (score 0):

The `spark.sessionState.conf.defaultDataSourceName` was introduced in Spark 2.2, source can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/40f9dbb6284ca6d5664ec0983faba723bc72d7f1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/CatalogImpl.scala#L283).

In Spark 2.1.1, setting this (either in configuration before connection or run time) worked for me:

```
spark_session_config(
  sc, "spark.sql.sources.default", "orc"
)
```